# Secure Drupal User Profile Information

Tags: 7, users

I need to secure the user profile information, which contains predefined & custom fields such as username, profile picture & phone number.

I do need to encrypt & store it in DB. And then decrypt to display output.

Do anyone know, does encryption for fields is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible only if you do it programatically for this. You can use [hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) and update encrypted values while saving user. And while retrieving data/fields you can decrypt with the key that you used for encryption and show in profile view page. Example:

```
/**
 *
 * @param array $edit
 * @param type $account
 * @param type $category
 */
function example_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $name = $edit['name']; // Get value of field.
  $edit['name'] = encrypt($name); // Encrypt and save.
}

/**
 * Returns encrypted string
 */
function encrypt($pure_string) {
  $encryption_key = 'SECRET';
  $encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($pure_string, "AES-128-ECB", $encryption_key);
  return $encrypted_string;
}

/**
 * Returns decrypted original string
 */
function decrypt($encrypted_string) {
  $encryption_key = 'SECRET';
  $decrypted_string = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_string, "AES-128-ECB", $encryption_key);
  return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for decryption i need to call this function, wherever it requires as it becomes so tedious. Do we have any hook to decrypt whenever account information is fetched?

Comment: There are no hooks for this. Write this encrypt and decrypt in any .inc file and include where necessary.

Comment: Yes there’s a hook for this @Prasanth: `hook_user_load`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://www.drupal.org/project/field_encrypt

> This module adds options to encrypt field values.
>
> The goal of this module is to create a method for encrypting field
>   values when stored in the database.
>
> This module depends on the Encrypt module
>   (http://drupal.org/project/encrypt) for encrypting and decrypting
>   strings.
>
> Install this module like any other module. Field encryption settings
>   are made on the field edit page.

Comment: I have installed it, but am not sure it exactly matches my requirement. As my fields were predefined one, username, email address, profile picture, phone number.

Comment: I am sure you will be able to do this using https://www.drupal.org/project/field_encrypt, along with https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt and https://www.drupal.org/project/dbee. Please go through the documentation